# Running Play Framework(blog-spark-food-recommendation) on Intellij IDEA,blog-spark-recommendation_2.10-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar not yet created

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

**It show's below error message**

Caused by: java.io.File NotFoundException:
 target/scala-2.10/blog-spark-recommendation_2.10-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar (No such file or directory)

target/scala-2.10/blog-spark-recommendation_2.10-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar file not yet created

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null

application - Error while rendering default error page

scala.MatchError: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (of class java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError)

Comment: me too got the same issue and searching for solution

Comment: its file not found exception .. seems there is no such jar file , so can you include blog-spark-recommendation_2.10-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar and check it

Comment: When we run application "blog-spark-recommendation_2.10-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" automatically downloaded in /target/scala-2.10 is it correct or we need to include manually